# Update a polygon that have intersections in two or more polygons

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, polygon, intersect

I have 2 tables, table #1 contains a square polygon/grid, table #2 contains the polygon of an administrative area. I updated table #1 with data from table #2 with the ST_Intersects() function. Here's an example of my query:

```sql
update table_grid 
set data1 = table_administrative.data1 
from table_administrative 
where ST_Intersects(table_grid.geom, table_administrative.geom)
```

How will the query run? and what about grids that have intersections in two or more administrative regions? Will it be chosen randomly, or the largest region, or based on the centroid?

An example of the case is as shown in the picture

[image: example grid that intersect two areas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about grids that have intersections in two or more administrative regions? Will it be chosen randomly, or the largest region, or based on the centroid?

Randomly, due to how [`update..from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8) works:

> When using `FROM` you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

Even if you see some repeatability in which ones it ends up using, it's unreliable. That being said, you can correct your query to explicitly select the specific one you want, based on your own criteria, like the proximity of centroid, overlapping area, or just picking *the one with lower/earlier id*, alphabetically.

Add a subquery with `distinct on`, `order by..limit 1` or `row_number()over()`. The [`<<->>`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_centroid_nd.html) bbox centroid distance operator might be useful: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bra4wsd6)

```sql
with cte as (select distinct on (tg.ctid) tg.ctid, data1
             from table_grid tg 
             join table_administrative ta
               on ST_Intersects(tg.geom,ta.geom)
             order by tg.ctid, tg.geom <<->> st_centroid)
update table_grid as this
set data1 = cte.data1
from cte
where this.ctid=cte.ctid
```

You might also be interested in [`ST_Subdivide()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html). If you subdivide the administrative areas with it, all these `join`s (and your `update` that joins implicitly) will be way faster. It'll also be a bit safer to downgrade `ST_Intersects()` to plain bounding box intersection [`&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) for added performance in case you plan to stick with the "direct" update, not minding the randomly resolved ties:

```sql
update __test.table_grid 
set data1 = table_administrative.data1 
from __test.table_administrative
where table_grid.geom && table_administrative.geom;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The first query you show is updating based on proximity of centroid right? how about the performance, is it faster by using a sub query like that or updating directly like I did?

Comment: and regarding ST_Subdivide(), I have used it considering that the grid data I handle is 1.5 billion rows, but do you have a recommendation for the max_vertices to use for my case?

Comment: @HermawanWiwid **1)** Proximity of the *bounding box* centroid, not the centroid of the actual geometry - just to be specific. **2)** There isn't much point to comparing performance of fundamentally different operations: these do more, attempting to give you predictable results. Between them, the CTE-based one will be faster. If you're really after speed, you can swap out `ST_Intersects()` for it's bbox-only version [`&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) - once you subdivide, it'll get you the same result faster, at the price of giving a different one in 1% cases.

Comment: **3)** That depends on the precision/vertex count of your administrative areas. Start with default 256 and see how things scale if you move down towards 5 from there. Aside from simpler shapes being easier on the memory, the main goal is to get the edge subsections of the larger shape to be small and specific, while having large "inside" areas exactly the shape of their bbox. Subdivision lets PostGIS skip most of the vertices and the ones left, are simple to compare to - especially the huge internal boxes. [Here's a nice demo.](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html)