# Is it faster updating based on matching strings or spatial join in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I work with PostGIS and quite large data of around 1.5 billion rows, I want to know which update is faster based on matching strings of one column with another column compared to spatial join (ST_Intersects)?

The query I mean is:

```sql
UPDATE table_grid AS gd
SET col_grid = col_adm
FROM table_adm de
WHERE ST_Intersects(de.geom, gd.geom);
```

versus:

```sql
UPDATE table_grid AS gd
SET col_grid = col_adm
FROM table_adm de
WHERE gd.col_match1 = de.col_match1
AND gd.col_match2 = de.col_match2
AND gd.col_match3 = de.col_match3;
```

Please give reasons why one query is faster than the other

Comment: That is impossible to say without knowing a lot more, but you have the data and the database and can ask it how these queries perform and make decisions based on that.

Comment: You can measure this yourself, no reason to ask anybody without access to your database. Use `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to get the query plan and the execution results from this plan.

Comment: Of course, the two queries aren't equivalent without additional (unmentioned) work being performed and you seem to be ignoring the costs of that work, so it's an unfair comparison anyway. Write the query that expresses your *logical intent* most clearly, set performance goals, *measure* your results and if they're not meeting your goals, experiment with variations but make sure you code the whole cost of your alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already underlined by the comments, without additional details that's a very abstract question. Based on your [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78125018/5298879), I'll assume that:

1. You aim for the two alternative updates to be functionally equivalent: find the same matches for the same rows, transfer the same values.
2. In both scenarios, you have an adequate index in place.
3. You're matching geometry shapes of an even grid with much larger, irregular (multi)polygons:
   [image]

In that case, the three-string match will be typically (much) faster. You can adjust the demo from the old thread and see the reason for yourself: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UlTYKmef)

1. The `join` on 3 `text` values is clear, precise and specific - Postgres knows the matched row based on the index alone. `Text`-to-`text` comparison in the `Index Cond` is fast and there's no `Filter` stage required.
2. In case of `ST_Intersects()`, the index only helps the first stage where it narrows down match candidates using a less precise bounding box intersection operator `&&`, but after that it has to perform a fairly expensive, vertex-by-vertex intersection check for all candidates on the `Filter` stage. `&&` descending down the [R-tree](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/the-many-spatial-indexes-of-postgis) is quick, but the final comparison has to do some planar/spherical geometry math, which will always be more expensive than a (hash) equality check it'd do if it just compared strings.

On 380 admin areas and 20k grid cells, 3-text match takes `50ms`, `st_intersects()` takes `300ms`.

I'm speeding up both updates by creating the `table_grid` with [`fillfactor=50`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR) - that way all pages of the table have 50% empty space so that when `update` comes, the new version of the tuple can be saved right behind the old version.

Although in the demo I made these functionally equivalent by establishing the 3-text match based on the `st_intersects()` in the first place, keep in mind the latter is undeterministic. As established [in the old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78125018/5298879), without additional match conditions, whenever a grid cell intersects more than one admin area, Postgres will match it unpredictably. A deterministic version of that intersection-based match will be even slower.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer! Your clear explanation and thorough examples really helped me understand the concept better. Much appreciated!